# Placing checkbox over an image without using 'top' and 'position:absolute'?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to put a checkbox over an image without using 'top' and 'position:absolute' ?

```
<div class="main">
<img src="http://www.standard.co.uk/incoming/article9760552.ece/binary/original/Rooney.jpg" class="image"/>
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k8tewjoL/)

Comment: Can i do it with 'position: absolute' and without 'top'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few possible ways.  If you want to avoid `top` and `absolute` you could position it using negative margins.  Or if you simply want checkbox to be checked when the image is clicked you could wrap the image in a label and tie the label to the checkbox.  I've done both [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOqLpw).

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
  <label for="checkbox">
    <img src="http://www.standard.co.uk/incoming/article9760552.ece/binary/original/Rooney.jpg" class="image" />
  </label>
  <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
}

input {
  display: block;
  margin-top: -200px;
  position: relative;
}
```

A quick explanation: `position: relative` allows the checkbox to sit on top of the image (`z-index` won't cut it here), the negative `margin-top` pulls it up onto the image, and `display: block` makes it so that the top margin can be applied (I'm not sure why it doesn't work on inline elements.)  I expected to have to use negative margins on `margin-left` as well, but it seems to naturally move to the left on it's own.  I'm not sure why for that either.  But it does work and it does not need `position: absolute` or `top`.

Comment: Ya..this is right answer..me too have a similar answer [link](http://jsfiddle.net/k8tewjoL/1/)